# Pyspark wrtting a data frame into csv but only driver is working

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a very huge parquet file into a CSV table with the following code.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test_parquet')
spark=SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('my_first_app_name') \
        .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load('hdfs://hadoop1:9001/data.parquet')
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save('hdfs://hadoop1:9001/data.csv')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7gAe.png)

But find that only the driver is working. That's too slow!! Can anyone help? Why other executors do not work?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyKnk.png)

Comment: You may get more answers faster if you remove images and use text to explain your issue.

Comment: Increase the number of executors :)))